# Similar solution like cronofy.com for contacts

Tags: google-api, google-contacts-api, outlook.com, icloud-api

With cronofy.com you can access the same API as a third party for services like Google Calendar, Outlook.com, iCloud etc to synchronise calendars. Do you know a similar solution for contacts? The aim would be, that you have the same endpoints and parameters for Google Contacts, Outlook.com, iCloud like cronofy does that for calendars. 
Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Cloudsponge.com](http://www.cloudsponge.com/test-drive/). Aside the HTML5 widget, it has several APIs to import contacts for [several languages and platforms](http://www.cloudsponge.com/integrations/).

**Disclaimer**: I work for CloudSponge.